# Why Tkinter can be procedural and PyQt can only be used just with the OO paradigm?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt

I have been programming in Python3 and use Tkinter to create GUIs. I have recently been introduced to PyQT and realise how much better the GUI toolkit is in terms of its style and range of widgets.

I have used Tkinter mostly in a procedural way and it works fine in terms of GUI building. I realise that PyQT uses the OOP paradigm to create GUIs.

Am I correct in thinking that the following correctly describes how tkinter and PyQT differ in the way in which they work...?

- With Tkinter, you produce a window object and then you create widget objects (buttons, labels etc) (all these widgets being separate objects) and each time you place them on your window like sticking different pictures on a piece of paper, **which is why you can create tkinter GUIs in a procedural way**.
- With PyQT however, you can produce a window object in the same way, but if you want widgets to appear on the window object you don't create them separately and 'stick them on' like with Tkinter. Instead, you have to create a new class (blueprint) for your window object, inherit the various widgets from the PyQT parent classes, create these widgets (objects) and build them into your new class (as attributes) so that when you instantiate your window object, it comes with all the widgets that was set up in the customised class for the window. And this is **why with PyQt it only works using the Object Orientated paradigm**.

Is this correct? If not, where is my understanding going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Tkinter and PyQt can both be written using either a procedural or an object-oriented style. However, I am reasonably certain that the large majority of example code available for both toolkits assumes that the latter style is predominant. I haven't written much Tkinter code, but it would never occur me that there is any significant difference between them in terms of general program structure.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason I assumed pyqt could only be programmed in OOP style is because of this quote..."Python programming language supports both procedural and object oriented programming styles. Programming in PyQt5 means programming in OOP"...which is written on the zetcode tutorial and also been mentioned on many other tutorials too.

Comment: @sw123456 You can do sticking with PyQt, but its not the preferred way. Its not really the preferred way with tkinter, using objects and classes is much cleaner.

Comment: @sw123456. Qt is a much, much larger project than Tkinter, and would best be described as "multi-paradigm". For sure, there is a strong emphasis on object-oriented programming, but Qt also includes technologies like [QML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML), which is mainly declarative. To me, your quote simply means: "If you use PyQt, expect to do a lot of OOP-style programming". But really, I think "PyQt" could be replaced with "$GUI_TOOLKIT" without too much controversy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thank all of you for helping me understand the errors in my understanding.

For any others who are introduced to PyQt (after coming from a tkinter background) and read tutorials that state that PyQt demands an OOP approach, the following two identical programs show that this is simply not the case (although, clearly, to build big apps, an OOP approach is advisable).

Procedural PyQt:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QToolTip,
    QPushButton, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QWidget()

QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
w.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

btn = QPushButton('Button', w)
btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
btn.move(50, 50)

w.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
w.setWindowTitle('Tool Tips')
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

OOP PyQt:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QToolTip,
    QPushButton, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))

        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you all for your comments and helping me realise my stupidity.

Answer (score 3):

I can only speak about tkinter, but *both* modes are useful.  Procedural code is useful for exploring with minimal boilerplate.  For instance, after running the following from an Idle editor (intentionally without a `mainloop()` call)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font

root = Tk()
spin = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=9, width=3,
               font=Font(family='Helvetica', size=36, weight='bold'))
spin.pack()
```

I can interactively experiment with changing the attributes of `spin`, such as by entering

```
>>> spin['fg'] = 'red'
>>> spin['fg'] = 'blue'
>>> spin['justify'] = 'right'
```

However, for a finished app of any complexity, I think it better to put gui setup code in a one or more methods of one or more classes.  For instance, Idle, a tkinter app, is composed of numerous classes that either subclass a widget or contain a widget.